# VBA: Check if file exists in a computer in domain

Tags: vba, dns, network-programming

Is there a way to check if a file exists in a PC in domain ?

I know that there is a way to check in local PC but I don' t know how to check in other PC in the same domain.

I have the administrator credentials to enter the PC I want to check.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code for local check we can modify?

Comment: I use a code like this for local check:

    Function esiste() As Boolean pathAssoluto As String:
      
    pathAssoluto = "C:\Programmi\Microsoft Office\bin\myFile.doc"
    If Not Dir(pathAssoluto, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        esiste = True End If End Function
    End If
    
    End Function

Comment: i ask help for formatting my code. I'm putting 4 spaces at begin of each line of my block code but this not work

Answer (score 0):

File paths to remote computers are `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`. So use that syntax. The wonders of Windows networking.

Comment: where i enter administrator credentials? do not them will be asked?

Comment: You right click the shortcut to the command prompt and choose *Run As Administrator*. In an already opened command prompt you use RunAs - see `RunAs /?`.

Comment: Ehm.. I'm searching a vba solution but many thanks for your suggest